# How to recursively assign a property?

Tags: c#, inheritance, recursion

I have a base, abstract class here:

```
public abstract class Group
{  
  public ParentGroup { get; set; }
}
```

I have two classes that derive from Group

```
public class LeafA : Group
public class GroupB : Group
```

So both of these classes have access to the ParentGroup property.

I am trying to recursively assign the ParentGroup property for each of these derived classes. The caveat is GroupB has a List component that can hold elements of type Group.

```
public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
```

This is the method I am trying to recursively assign the ParentGroup

```
private void AssignParentGroup(GroupB GroupElement)
{
  foreach (Group component in GroupElement.Groups)
  {
    if (component is GroupB)
     {
       // Recursive call here
      }
    }
  }
```

This is just an example but if my GroupB GroupElement has two elements in the Groups: 1 is GroupB and the other LeafA. GroupB can hold x amount of Groups, so I would like to recursively go through all of these SubGroups and assign the ParentGroup. The ParentGroup would be something like ->

```
GroupB -> Groups -> {Group1, Group2} (ParentGroup = GroupB)
```

Hope this was clear. Please let me know if I can explain.

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for something like:

```
private void AssignParentGroup(Group groupElement, Group parentGroup)
{
    // the groupElement has always a ParentGroup property. assign it.
    groupElement.ParentGroup = parentGroup;

    // if the class is a GroupB, then is has subGroups. Pass the groupElement as parent.
    if(groupElement is GroupB groupB)
        foreach(var subGroup in groupB.Groups)
            AssignParentGroup(subGroup, groupElement);
}
```

---

Call it like:

```
AssignParentGroup(someGroup, null);
```

Or make the `parentGroup` parameter default `null` for the first call:

```
private void AssignParentGroup(Group groupElement, Group parentGroup = null)
```

You can extend this code, and check what to do when it is a `LeafA` class

Comment: Ahh, I see what hes going for. Deleting my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem by implementing the Visitor pattern.

First, I'd add the accept method to my abstract class.

```
public abstract class Group
{
    public Group ParentGroup { get; set; }
    public abstract void Accept(GroupVisitor visitor);
}
```

I'd implement the boilerplate for derived classes.

```
public class LeafA : Group {
    public override void Accept(GroupVisitor visitor){
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}
public class GroupB : Group
{
    public List<Group> Groups {get;set;}
    public override void Accept(GroupVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}
```

Then implement the group visitor like so:

```
public class GroupVisitor {
    private Group _parent;
    public GroupVisitor(Group parent) {
        _parent = parent;
    }

    public void Visit(LeafA leaf) {
        leaf.ParentGroup = _parent;
    }

    public void Visit(GroupB group) {
        group.ParentGroup = _parent;
        var visitor = new GroupVisitor(group);
        foreach (var item in group.Groups)
            item.Accept(visitor);

    }
}
```

As a result, we can assign the parents to a group hierarchy like so:

```
var visitor = new GroupVisitor(someGroup.ParentGroup);
someGroup.Accept(visitor);
```

This will handle both the assignment of parents to LeafA as well as GroupB.